# Wordpress with divi theme doesn't show images on mobile

Tags: wordpress

my girlfriend has this site: http://merryfullife.si/

On desktop everything is OK (&chrome developer tools), but on mobiles some images just doesn't load. I tried:
- on wifi or mobile data
- different wifi's
- different mobile phones

Comment: which image not loading in mobile?

Comment: On index page only two small images are loaded?

Comment: background images are not loading?

Comment: Check divi theme options, you need to enable mobile ,tab option.

Comment: Background and normal images are not showing - it is no diference. On this page: http://merryfullife.si/djotis/ only the first background image is shown, no other. Samyappa, i didnt find this option?

Answer (score 1):

**SSL Causing Images Not to Display**

After WordPress 4.4 versions, The issue is with SSL causing images not to display.
Better get SSL Certificate for your site. :)

Read [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/responsive-images-src-url-is-https-srcset-url-is-http-no-images-loaded/)

For Divi Themes, read the issue [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/ssl-causing-images-not-to-display-heres-how-to-fix-it)